# Ellipsis and va_args trick needed

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, trace, etw

[TraceMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an WinAPI function with variable number of arguments. It is a tracing function, with a notation similar to printf, which generates a trace message in Windows tracing. The weird part here is that it receive a format string as part of the ellipsis, not as a dedicated argument.
It is possible to 'override' this function with a function of my own, which then needs to call [TraceMessageVa](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364140%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which is the same as TraceMessage, just with va_args rather than ellipsis).

So far so good; but now I want to access the traced message using a `sprintf`-like function, which has the format string out of the ellipsis. Thus I need to
 - get the format string argument out of the ellipsis ;
 - create a new va_list without the first argument.

Any idea about to how do it? Solutions specific to Visual Studio compiler are also acceptable. Thanks!

Comment: The docs for TraceMessage do not say that it does what you say it does.

Comment: That is correct, but you should believe me or just treat this as a question about ellipsis and va_args, regardless of the tracing context...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a `va_list` you can pass it to a function which takes a `va_list` after having used `va_arg` on it already to have extracted one or more arguments. The `va_list` will then act like it "contains" only the rest of the arguments.

I have no experience with `TraceMessage` itself, but I've given an example using standard `vprintf` and a test function. You should be able to adapt as appropriate.

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void test(int a, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    const char* x;

    va_start(va, a);
    x = va_arg(va, const char*);

    vprintf(x, va);

    va_end(va);
}

int main(void)
{
    test(5, "%d\n", 6);
    return 0;
}
```